# How To Filter Both Rows And Columns On Multiple Criteria In Excel

Tags: excel-formula

As an example, see the below data.

[image]

I can `FILTER` by row with:

```
=FILTER($A$1:$E$9,
((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9)))+
(IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE))+
(IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE))))
```

I can also `FILTER` by column with:

`=FILTER($A$1:$E$9, $A$1:$E$1="1600m")`

But when I try to filter by both simultaneously, I get `#VALUE!`.

Below are my two tries:

1)

```
=FILTER($A$1:$E$9,
((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9)))+
(IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE))+
(IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE)))*
($A$1:$E$1="1600m"))
```

2. 

```
=FILTER($A$1:$E$9,
((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9)))+
(IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE))+
(IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE))*
($A$1:$E$1="1600m")))
```

I have also thought about utilizing `LET` to first filter by column, and then filter the already filtered array by row, but I don't believe I can reference specific rows in the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had succes with it using FILTER twice, one for the columns, one for the rows: `=FILTER(FILTER([range],[conditions_column]),[conditions_row])`

Comment: Just realizing that I might misunderstand your expected output - do you want H1:E5 in your example above as the output?

Comment: It's important to start with the column, since filtering the rows may result in losing the header you're filtering on

Comment: btw - the `IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE)` is interesting. I've not seen that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can index your row filter:

```
=INDEX(
    FILTER(A1:E9,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9))+
           (IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE))+
           (IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE)))),
    , MATCH( "1600m", $A$1:$E$1,0) )
```

If you don't want the header:

```
=INDEX(
    FILTER(A1:E9, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9) +
           IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE) +
           IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE))),
    , MATCH( "1600m", $A$1:$E$1,0) )
```

As P.b. proposed, nested FILTER can be done to deliver the result with header:

```
=FILTER( FILTER( $A$1:$E$9, $A$1:$E$1="1600m"),
            (ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9)) +
            (IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE)) +
            (IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE))) )
```

If the output needs to be as shown in H1:E5 of your image, this *(over-engineered for illustration)* LET delivers it, just in case:

```
=LET(t, $A$1:$E$9, list, $A$1:$A$9, horse, "b", raceDist, "1600m",
      raceHeader, INDEX(t, 1, ),
      rf, FILTER(t, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(horse,list)) +
                            IFERROR(list="List",FALSE) +
                            IFERROR(list="",FALSE) ),
      idxR, SEQUENCE(ROWS(rf)),
      rf_rowLabels, INDEX(rf,idxR,{1,2}),
      target, INDEX( rf, , MATCH( raceDist, raceHeader, 0 ) ),
      IFERROR( INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(rf,SEQUENCE(ROWS(rf)),{1,2}),0,""), idxR,{1,2,3}),
               target )  )
```

> Edited out the first SUBSTITUTE - I forgot that it was still there. Thanks P.b.

Comment: I love the way you engineer these things (LET-approach). See my answer for my approach of nested FILTER to include the `Event:` and `Year` columns

Comment: Nice touch on adding the substitute over `rf` where value = 0. I tried removing it in rf_rowlabels and expected the first cell of the spill-range to show 0, but it remained blank.

Comment: @P.b - I almost suggested the same for yours, but got a phone call. Yours made me think that, I made a mistake with the SUBSTITUTE. It should have been applied to rf_rowlabels, but I accidentally did it twice because I forgot that I had already done it. I guess I will go clean that up.

Comment: Splendid. Love your approaches

Answer (score 3):

`=FILTER( FILTER($A$1:$E$9,($A$1:$E$1="1600m")+($A$1:$E$1="Event:")+($A$1:$E$1="")), ((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",$A$1:$A$9)))+ (IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="List",FALSE))+ (IFERROR($A$1:$A$9="",FALSE))))`
First the conditions for the column headers, followed by the conditions for your rows.

PS Empty cells are displayed as `0`[image]

Comment: Super clean and, once again, done on your phone - that's crazy for me.